# How to handle tmp files in php?

Tags: php

I need to use TMP file while script is working, is it possible to save tmp for a while??? For example this code:

```
function doTmp($some_data) {
    $tmp_handle = tmpfile();
    $meta_datas = stream_get_meta_data($tmp_handle);
    $tmp_local_uri = $meta_datas['uri'];

    file_put_contents($tmp_local_uri, $some_data);

    var_dump(file_exists($tmp_local_uri));

    return $tmp_local_uri;
}

$test = doTmp('lololo');
var_dump(file_exists($test));
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[tempnam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)** documentation and use it.

If you do not need to know the name of the temporary file you should use **[tmpfile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php)** instead.